# SQL Loader incompatible length

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

This is my control file

```
FIELDS (
  dummy1  filler  terminated by "cid=",
  address         enclosed by "<address>" and "</address>"
...
```

The `address` column in the table is `varchar(10)`.

If the address in the file is over 10 characters then SQL*Loader cannot load it.

How I can capture address truncating to 10 characters?

Comment: It's useful to show the actual error you get - presumably "ORA-12899: value too large for column..." since you haven't specified the column size in the control file? If you'd declared it there are `char(10)` you'd have got a different error, "Field in data file exceeds maximum length", from SQL\*Loader itself rather than the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation has a section on [applying SQL operators to fields](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226).

> A wide variety of SQL operators can be applied to field data with the SQL string. This string can contain any combination of SQL expressions that are recognized by the Oracle database as valid for the `VALUES` clause of an `INSERT` statement. In general, any SQL function that returns a single value that is compatible with the target column's datatype can be used.

In this case you can use the `substr()` function on the value from the file:

```
...
  dummy filler  terminated by "cid=",
  address enclosed by "<address>" and "</address>" "substr(:address, 1, 10)"
...
```

The quoted `"substr(:address, 1, 10)"` passes the initial value from the file through the function before inserting the resulting 10 character (maximum) value, however long the original value in the file was. Note the colon before the name in that function call.

---

If your file is XML then you might be better off loading it as [an external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm) and then using the built-in XML query tools to extract the data you want, rather than trying to parse it through delimited field definitions.

Comment: thanks but I'm analyzing sql loader in this way to highlight the problems with the load xml sql loader .
It s possibile with sql loader  do: if length > 10 put a default value ?

Comment: Sure, just as you would with a query, maybe `"case when length(:address) > 10 then 'default' else :address end"`.